# magento restrict website to certain country

Tags: cms

i want to disable my site for certaing country and redirect it to specific page only like if person from UK opens website he will be redirected to abc.com/restricted

which is cms page with some message and shows user ip

Comment: tried nothing just looking any such type of setting in admin ??

Comment: Ah ok. Magento can't do that out of the box. What you want is something like geoip or depending on the choosen language of the user redirect him. This is a tough topic if you want to do it right. Give google a try with magento and geoip

Comment: @FabianBlechschmidt. You can put your last comment as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Magento can't do that out of the box. What you want is something like geoip or depending on the choosen language of the user redirect him. This is a tough topic if you want to do it right. Give google a try with magento and geoip